# Using spacy v3 which parameter should I change in the config file to resolve CUDA out of memory problem ? batch_size vs max_length vs batcher.size

Tags: machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

Using spacy v3, I try to train a classifier using camemBert and got `CUDA out of memory` problem.
To resolve this issue I read that I should decrease the batch size but I'm confused which parameter should I change between :

- [nlp] batch_size
- [components.transformer] max_batch_items
- [corpora.train or dev] max_length
- [trainning.batcher] size
- [trainning.batcher] buffer

I tried to understand the difference between each parameter :

1. **[nlp] batch_size**

> Default batch size for pipe and evaluate. Defaults to 1000.

Are those functions used in the training / evaluating process ?
In the quickstart widget (https://spacy.io/usage/training#quickstart), why are the value different according to the hardware ? 1000 for CPU and 128 for GPU.
During the training process, will be the evaluation slower if this value is low ?

2. **[components.transformer] max_batch_items**

> Maximum size of a padded batch. Defaults to 4096.

According to the warning message : `Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (556 > 512). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors` explained here (https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/6939),
Camembert model has a specified maximum sequence length of 512.

Is the parameter max_batch_item overloaded to this value ? Should I change the value to 512 ?

3. **[corpora.train or dev] max_length**

In my comprehension, this value should be equal or lower to the maximum sequence length.
In the quickstart widget this value is set to 500 for the training set and 0 for the dev set.
If set to 0, will it be overloaded to the maximum sequence length of the transformer model ?

4. **[trainning.batcher] size for spacy.batch_by_padded.v1**

> The largest padded size to batch sequences into. Can also be a block referencing a schedule, e.g. compounding.

If I don't use compounding, in what this parameter is different of the max_lentgh ?

Here are some parts of my config file

```
[nlp]
lang = "fr"
pipeline = ["transformer","textcat"]
# Default batch size to use with nlp.pipe and nlp.evaluate
batch_size = 256
...

[components.transformer]
factory = "transformer"
# Maximum size of a padded batch. Defaults to 4096.
max_batch_items = 4096
...

[corpora.dev]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.dev}
# Limitations on training document length
max_length = 512
...

[training.batcher]
@batchers = "spacy.batch_by_padded.v1"
discard_oversize = true
# The largest padded size to batch sequences into. Can also be a block referencing a schedule, e.g. compounding.
size = 500
# The number of sequences to accumulate before sorting by length. A larger buffer will result in more even sizing, but if the buffer is very large, the iteration order will be less random, which can result in suboptimal training.
buffer = 128
get_length = null
...
```

Comment: Response here : https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8600

Answer (score 1):

How much memory does your GPU have?

Under Spacy 2.x, I was able to use a 6GB GPU. But (if memory serves me right) Spacy 3 documentation recommends 10-12 GB.
I tried various parameters, but my GPU 6GB memory is mostly used up by the PyTorch load, and hence I 'run out of GPU memory' fairly soon regardless of the batch_size  tweaking. And this applies not only to transformers, but also to the plain NR EntityRecognizer - Spacy 3 simply loads GPU with much more 'stuff' than Spacy 2 used to.

Comment: I have 16GB. But for now, the only way I could resolve the OOM exception si to set discard_oversize = true

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem of CUDA out of memory.  reducing batch size under [nlp] alone did not solve the problem. I then reduced batcher size to 250 then 125, it worked. it takes a lot longer but to be expected with smaller batch size

Comment: Can be a Comment...